# camera view as a texture?

Tags: texturing, camera

Is there any way i can use the camera view as a texture in realtime? i know you could do this in the blender game editor before using python, but now i don't know if there is a way i can use the camera view as a texture (or colour output, basically) without rendering or baking it

kind of like a security guard monititor or a portal effect, i think you could do this kind of effect in the compositor using masks but that wouldn't really help

Comment: I Lately thought a lot about this. I think the easiest way is to write an osl shader, which translates secondary rays by a vector. Don't know how to do this tho.

Comment: I'm looking for this too; to make something like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWnC9tSA3iA.  Did you find out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use python for Scripting. I have not tried it yet but from searching web there are commands to put in script to render the camera's view, save that to file, then set object texture to file, write another script to constantly update the objects texture.

Render camera view to file.
Set texture to file. 
Keep rendering and updating texture in background script.

Comment: ah cool thanks! i don't know much python but if you get any updates on that please let me know